# Why are opinion based questions not allowed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign

I was wondering, why opinion based questions are not allowed ? Can't we have discussion(s) on questions ? I understand this is question-answer community but if it is not good idea then can we request new feature for discussion ? :P

P.S: Chat rooms are for discussion but I doubt it will get attention of many users.

Comment: As pointed out in the answers, the SE network generally discourages opinion-based questions. If you'd like to propose a new feature to better enable discussions, please make it more specific : ) (but keep in mind that odds are it will be declined).

Comment: @ThomasOrozco, Sure. I try to get more specific details about such features. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the answer from @WYSIWYG; the entire StackExchange network generally discourage opinion-based questions and discussions (see e.g. [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192461/question-of-type-what-is-the-best-why-not-where-to-go?lq=1)  and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167516/how-can-i-encourage-stack-overflow-to-rein-in-the-subjective-vigilantes/200144#200144) post at meta.stackexchange.com). StackExchange sites are not discussion forums but places to ask and answer specific questions. If you want to have open-ended discussions you should choose another platform, or use the chat feature.

On the other hand, discussions about the policies and features of BiologySE or other StackExchange sites **are** allowed at their respective meta sites.

Comment: I liked your links however I disagree with [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). I think, it is not true that real questions have answers. There are many important questions which are debatable and have multiple answers (not subjective but scientific answers with contrasting explanations). These posts doesn't talk about such questions.

Comment: @Dexter Questions on topics that are contended or where the scientific evidence is inconclusive is definitely on-topic for the site (the question has an answer, but we don't know for sure what it is yet). The *opinion-based* close is meant for questions asking for purely subjective opinions or questions based on anecdotes. Sure, how to weight strength of evidence has a subjective element to it, but as long as questions and answers is based on actual (scientific) evidence they are fine.

Answer (score 3):

Opinion based posts are those that cannot be rationalized with either logic or references. We cannot have vague discussions; it is impossible to contain them. If a topic is precise then it should have a defined answer.

Regarding chat:

If users are not willing to use the chat for discussions then they perhaps are not interested at all.